# Printing a star (*) pattern with different decreasing number

Tags: c

The program is about printing a following pattern:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * *  (13 stars)
* * * * * * * * * * *      (11 stars)
* * * * * * * *            ( 8 stars)
* * * * *                  ( 5 stars)
* *                        ( 2 stars)
```

The logic I found is that when its greater 11 then it will print `(i-2)` on next line and if 
its less then or equal to 11 then will print `(i-3)`.

I do not expect a ready program but will be quite happy with the explanation also.

Comment: @devnull I know it but the logic behind this is different.

Comment: You know the logic, go ahead code it.

Comment: Home work try your own...this is just loops game:)

Comment: can i get some hint(s) @Umair?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n=14, c, k, temp;

    temp = n;

    for ( c = 0 ; c <= 4 ; c++ )
    {
        for( k = 2 ; k <= temp ; k++ )
            printf("*");

        if(k<=13)
        {
             temp=temp-3;
        }
        else
        {
        temp=temp-2;
        } 
     printf("\t\t%d",k-2);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wondering what will be the general term of such a sequence. Once you know it coding is easy.

Let me reveal that for all such sequences with some finite number of terms there are infinitely many representations for it. So there is no point in arguing or worrying whether your interpretation of the sequence is right or wrong. So your logic of generating the number is correct, although it us not the only correct answer.For example an another possible solution would be [image]

You can find any such possible solution, in mathematics finding out a possible function to represent all the set of point is termed as interpolation. Here is an [interpolation calculator](http://www.solvemymath.com/online_math_calculator/interpolation.php)